# Pydev debugger returns exit code 142

Tags: python, debugging, pydev, exit-code

A script I am debugging in `PyCharm` (which uses the `PyDev` debugger, build 135.1057), returns with **exit code 142**. I have had trouble finding documentation of the meanings of the different exit codes.

Can someone enlighten me, or provide me with a link to the appropriate documentation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From page 97 of the [Pytest docs](http://pytest.org/latest/pytest.pdf):

```
failure_demo.py:142:ValueError
```

---

```
______TestRaises.test_reinterpret_fails_with_print_for_the_fun_of_it______     

self=<failure_demo.TestRaisesobjectat0x2aec3e4cc438>

def test_reinterpret_fails_with_print_for_the_fun_of_it(self): 
    l=[1,2,3] 
    print("lis%r"%l) > E a,b=l.pop()
    TypeError:’int’objectisnotiterable
```